# Run script on start-up before specific network card is initialized

Tags: boot, networking, bash

I have a system with multiple network cards. How can I run a shell script before a *specific* network card is initialized on start-up?

I am running Ubuntu 15.10.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest start reading the post [how-to-write-startup-script-for-systemd](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47695/how-to-write-startup-script-for-systemd), than having a look at the man pages from which I got:

> systemd knows various kinds of dependencies, including positive and
>          negative requirement dependencies (i.e.  Requires= and Conflicts=) as
>          well as ordering dependencies (After= and Before=). NB: ordering and
>          requirement dependencies are orthogonal. If only a requirement
>          dependency exists between two units (e.g.  foo.service requires
>          bar.service), but no ordering dependency (e.g.  foo.service after
>          bar.service) and both are requested to start, they will be started in
>          parallel.

From which I understand the loading of services can be ordered.